# How do I reduce the thickness of the line in nutrition facts table?

Tags: html, css-tables

I have a nutrition facts table here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JackTurisma/Uv7Tq/

```
<div style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">
```

I want to reduce the thickness of the line to make it look prettier.

I am new to HTML I have tried changing everything and it didn't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You use a table data element (td) for that effect. So remove the `&nbsp;` in that td and set the height of the td like so:

```
<td colspan="3" style="height: 1px;" bgcolor="#000"></td>
```

instead of:

```
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="#000">&nbsp;</td>
```

But you would better of learning css and not use a table or html for styling purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can changing the thickness of the line by CSS `line-height` ant height of the element `height:

```
.thick {
  line-height:5px;
  height:5px;
}
```

Or you can use border instead of black lines

```
.border{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

This code you will place into the `<style></style>` tags and in html call `<td colspan="3" class="thick">nbsp;</td>`

`#a` = `id="a"`

`.b` = `class="b"`

Maybe this helps you: http://www.cssbasics.com/introduction-to-css/

Answer (score 0):

I would completely remove the tr's like the below:

```
<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

and i would add `border-bottom: 1px solid;` to the td's like the below:

```
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="white"><strong>Amount Per Serving</strong></td>
```

and the above will become:

```
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="white" style="border-bottom: 1px solid;"><strong>Amount Per Serving</strong></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The table markup needs a rewrite rather than tuning. Remove the rows with elements `<td colspan="3" style="height: 1px;" bgcolor="#000"></td>`. Set `border` properties on cells as desired. To create a continuous horizontal line, it is best to remove the `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes, set `border-collapse: collapse` in CSS and use the CSS `padding` properties for suitable alignment of columns (to that there is sufficient space between the data items).